# Row maximums in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, max

I have a 10 by 3 matrix (called u_V) and I would like to know in which column I have my row maximum. I know how to do it with `which.max` for a given row, and I coded as such to get the info for each row:

```
u <- rbind(which.max(u_V[1, 1:3]), which.max(u_V[2, 1:3]), which.max(u_V[3,  1:3]), 
which.max(u_V[4, 1:3]), + which.max(u_V[5, 1:3]), which.max(u_V[6, 1:3]),
which.max(u_V[7, 1:3]), which.max(u_V[8, 1:3]), + which.max(u_V[9, 1:3]),
which.max(u_V[10, 1:3]))
u
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to get those results, with a loop or something. Because at the moment I fixed the rows at 10 but it might change and I don't want to code in the same way for 50 rows. Just to be sure my question is clear, I don't really care what the value of the maximum is but in to which column it corresponds.

Comment: This is off-topic here as a request for code. Anywhere but R-help or equivalent forums dedicated to single languages, it's polite and informative to specify the language you are using, here presumably R.

Comment: Indeed sorry for that, wasn't totally focused on what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the `apply` answer is to use `max.col`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(nrow=10,ncol=3,data=runif(3*10))
max.col(x)
#  [1] 3 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 2
identical(max.col(x), apply(x, 1, which.max))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that.  I see max.col is an internal method, and thus faster. (Updated timings in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nick Cox, but seeing as I had R open and had mentally processed the answer, here you go (with some example data)

```
> x<-matrix(nrow=10,ncol=3,data=runif(3*10))
> x
             [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
 [1,] 0.861535956 0.2773221 0.7394190
 [2,] 0.763581333 0.5791367 0.2645617
 [3,] 0.339701933 0.6610865 0.8578069
 [4,] 0.783707450 0.7398291 0.2323307
 [5,] 0.005491861 0.1027971 0.3293975
 [6,] 0.491010167 0.2331927 0.9522282
 [7,] 0.445526237 0.2195360 0.5979696
 [8,] 0.372839795 0.9215390 0.2849639
 [9,] 0.276297446 0.8179302 0.4035756
[10,] 0.735914381 0.8797293 0.3853151
> apply(x, 1, which.max)
 [1] 1 1 3 1 3 3 3 2 2 2
>
```

**UPDATE**
as @Ananda has observed, there is actually a native function to do what you want.  As such it is what you want to use in practice.  I think my answer is still fine though :)

```
> m<-100000;n<-100;x<-matrix(nrow=m,ncol=n,data=runif(m*n))
> ptm <- proc.time()
> y<-max.col(x)
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.06   36.78 
> ptm <- proc.time()
> z<-apply(x, 1, which.max)
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   0.51    0.38   20.83 
>
```